# Convergence of this integral related to Riemann-Zeta Function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-zeta

Is it possible to show that for $Re(s)>0$ the following integral converges.

$$\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \left[{x^{\frac{s}{2}-1} + x^{-\frac{s+1}{2}} }\right] \omega \left({x}\right)dx$$

Where $\omega \left({x}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-\pi n^2x}$. I know that it converges for $Re(s)>1$ but I would like to know if there is a way of proving convergence for $Re(s)>0$.

Comment: Hint: $\int_1^\infty \frac{x^s}{e^{x}}dx$ converges for every $s$.

Comment: Are you sure that is true? Do you mean for every s with $Re(s)>0$

Comment: yes, for Re$(s)>0$.

Comment: @REr Hi there, bit of a late response but I can't quite figure out the details. Could you give me some ideas